# Error with creating and making key and visible a new UIWindow

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, uinavigationcontroller, uiwindow

i get this this error about 5 or 10 seconds after creating a new `UIWindow` and making it key and visible.

```
unexpected nil window in _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent, _windowServerHitTestWindow: (null)
```

It then brings me back to the old `UIWindow`. My code is below:

```
actionButton.TouchUpInside += delegate
{
    var window = new UIWindow();
    AppDelegate.NavController = new UINavigationController(new MainViewController());
    window.RootViewController = AppDelegate.NavController;
    window.Frame = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds;
    window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
};
```

All I am really trying to do is break from the hierarchy and start a new stack of view controllers via the `UINavigationCOntroller`. Let me know, thanks!

Comment: Is there any reason why you must do this? It seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @davetw12 what exactly? My code or wanting to break from the hierarchy of view controllers?

Comment: Wanting to break away from the hierarchy.

Comment: @davetw12 I have a series of sign up and information screens if it is the first time the user is opening the app, so after the user has completed these screens, I take them to the `MainViewController` and i'd like to make this the new `RootViewController`. I want to make it the root view controller because after the user completes a game, I just `PopToRootViewController`

Answer (score 0):

```
var window = new UIWindow();
```

Your `UIWindow` is a local variable, you need to hold a reference to it somewhere, make it a class level var and your troubles should go away (same as your static `AppDelegate.NavController` would work).

As a quick test, just put a `GC.Collect();` somewhere after the `window.MakeKeyAndVisible()` and start using the controls on your `MainViewController` and wait for the fun to begin. ;-)

Update:

I just realized that you reused the `CGRect` from the current Window, create a new one to have a clean separation in case you are changing the screen orientation, GLES size, etc..

```
window.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height + 100);
```